How to eliminate part of a linear ODE Mathematica solution that diverges for some values of the independent variable
I have the following linear ODE for which I want to find solutions that do not diverge for any value of $\theta$ with $0\le \theta \le \pi$ :$$T_n''[\theta]-\cot[\theta] T_n'[\theta]+n(n+1)T_n[\theta]=0$$This Mathematica program generates the solutions for the first five values of n, starting with $n = 1$ :$$Table[DSolve[T_n''[\theta]-\cot[\theta] T_n'[\theta]+n(n+1)T_n[\theta]==0,T_n[\theta],\theta],(n,5)]$$  where the last term$(n,5)$is supposed to be surrounded by curly brackets in Mathematica.  In general, the solutions for $T_n[\theta]$  have two terms, the first term multiplied by the constant $c_1$and the second term by the constant $c_2$.  For example, $$T_1[\theta] = c_1(\cos^2 \theta - 1)+\frac{1}{4}c_2 \left(-\log(\cos \theta-1)\cos^2\theta+...\right)$$and$$T_2[\theta] = c_1\cos \theta(\cos^2\theta - 1)+\frac{1}{4}c_2 \left(-3\log(\cos \theta -1)\cos^3\theta +... \right)$$But for $0\le \theta \le \pi$ we have $-1\le \cos\theta \le +1$, so the second terms diverge for some values of $\theta$, and therefore we must have $c_2 = 0$ for these two values of $n$, and similarly for all values of $n$ (I think, but have not proved).  Interestingly, these functions (the terms preceded by $c_1$) are orthogonal over the integral from $-1$ to $+1$  with the weight function $W[x] = \frac{1}{1-x^2}$ and $\cos \theta = x$, and they are not the Chebtshev polynomials that have the same symbol $T_n$ .  So the question is this: Using Mathematica, how can the divergent terms be automatically eliminated that are preceded by $c_2$ so that I just end up with the $c_1$ terms that converge for all $\theta$ ?

Equation:
DSolve[T''[t] - Cot[t]*T'[t] + n*(n + 1)*T[t] == 0, T, t]

has the following exact solution:
(*  T -> Function[{t}, 
  C[1] Hypergeometric2F1[-(1/2) - n/2, n/2, 1/2, Cos[t]^2] + 
   I  C[2]  Cos[t]  Hypergeometric2F1[1/2 + n/2, -(n/2), 3/2, 
     Cos[t]^2]]   *)

Does not seem to diverge at n=5, or whatever. Let us check:
Manipulate[
 Plot[Hypergeometric2F1[-(1/2) - n/2, n/2, 1/2, 
   Cos[\[Theta]]^2], {\[Theta], 0, \[Pi]}], {n, Range[6]}]


Have fun!

Thank you very much for the Manipulated Plot which does indeed show no divergences for (apparently) any values of n .  But if one does a Series expand of those Hypergeometric2F1 functions for \cos \theta  = x , one gets infinite series for some of the functions, while some give a finite series.  The only difference between the two ODEs that we are solving is that for the one that I use above, the dependent variable is T_n, while in the ODE that you use, the dependent variable is T without the subscript.  So something is wrong here:all finite series for T_n , some infinite series for T.

Both types of solutions take c_2 = 0 .

" The only difference between the two ODEs that we are solving is that for the one that I use above, the dependent variable is T_n, while in the ODE that you use, the dependent variable is T without the subscript. " There is no difference. The only difference is that you write it for whatever reason, and I do not.

When I Plot the two different solutions, I get that the Plots are the same for odd n, and different for even n even though they both converge for the range. The solutions using the cosine function can be easily verified to be correct. I agree, there should be no difference, but something seems wrong.

OK. That's up to you.

I think Mathematica is sometimes wrong, this case shows it clearly to me because the solutions for the same ODE in slightly different forms give radically different results. And I have noticed other errors in the past.  Here is a helpful Reddit post on this subject: https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/1c25llh/can_wolfram_ever_get_wrong_answers/
